# Best Practice for saving a DataGridView after the contents of a cell have been deleted

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has a text box column that the user can modify. I was running into an issue where when the user deletes the text out of one of the cells and tries to save it, it would though an Obj Ref error when I tried to access the cell that the text was previously deleted from.

The way I got around this was when the user is done editing a cell I put a handler on the the 
"CellEndEdit" event. In the method I check to see if the cell IsNothing I set the value to be an empty string.

I was wondering if this is the best practice for that sort of thing.

Comment: Check if the underlying data source allows empty (or null) in that particular fields. Second, you are not deleting the row, you are just updating it with empty cell, so the event you are using seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `DataSourceNullValue` property to `String.Empty` for that cell.  Then when the user deletes the contents of the cell, an empty string will automatically be set in the database.  You will not have to handle the `CellEndEdit` event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.datasourcenullvalue.aspx